# Does codenameone support activity detection which uses CMMotionActivity (IOS) and Google Play Services ActivityRecognition API (android)?

Tags: codenameone

Being a Java developer, i am super excited to use codenameone for an app that I am planning to write from scratch. But would like to know if codenameone supports activity detection which uses CMMotionActivity in case of ios or Google Play Services ActivityRecognition API in case of android ?

Particularly, my app would like to receive events when the user is stationary, walking, running, cycling, driving/automotive etc. Also, if i can fine tune the battery usage settings in case of location services subscription as provided by Google play services location apis, that would be great.

I hope i wont get disappointed. I was planning to learn codenameone and use it in my app only if these above features are available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid they aren't available out of the box. However, Codename One is very flexible and you can use native interfaces to expose these features by [invoking native code](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html).

Comment: thanks @Shai Almog. Too bad for me that these features are not available out of the box. Does it mean codename one is not actively being developed or not so popular with the open source community ? I am wondering if in that case i should rather go for phonegap-cordova or appcelerometer.

Comment: Are these features exposed via the JavaScript layer of Cordova? Usually our support is broader e.g. calendar API which they don't seem to have. This just means that very few people asked for them before and none of them were high ranking paying customers who insisted on it. You can see some of the community contributed third party native libraries for Codename One here: http://codenameone.com/cn1libs.html in the changes tab here you can see just how active Codename One is: code.google.com/p/codenameone/source/ as well as here http://codenameone.com/discussion-forum.html

Comment: Thanks @Shai Almog. The links look good. I will start learning codename one and do a POC to use those native features. Again, thanks for your support !! Biggest Codenname One positive for me is that i can write in Java..as against to javascript.. yes.. I am not a web guy